# How do I read in csv data from my Knack database with knackpy?

Tags: python, database

I'm a beginner to using Knack and knackpy so forgive me if this is an easy fix.

I'm trying to use `knackpy` to read in data from my Knack dataset and graph it with `plotly`.

I'm essentially trying to replicate [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSzic.jpg) with this code, but by reading in the data from Knack:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
...
birthday_data = pd.read_csv("birthdays.csv")
fig2 = px.bar(birthday_data, x = 'employee_name', y = 'birthday', title='birthdays')
fig2.show()
```

Knack code:

```
import knackpy
app = knackpy.App(app_id = "my-app-id",  api_key = "my-api-key")
records = app.get("knack_birthdays")
fig3 = px.bar(records, x = 'employee_name', y = 'birthday', title='birthdays')
fig3.show()
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['field_3', 'field_4', 'id'] but received: employee_name

My Knack variables are set up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YoC0.jpg).

In the variables, `birthday_data` is a `DataFrame` type variable, while `records` is a `list`.

Is this just a syntax issue or am I setting up the database incorrectly?
Please add a comment if you need clarification.

Comment: This is a plotly error. You are passing it a dataframe (records) which misses the columns you are passing to x and y. Check how your dataframe is structure -print describe e.g-. 
If you replace the employee_name and the birthday with field_3 and field_4 it should work

Comment: That did print out a graph, but almost in like "reverse order", with the names and dates reversed. Take a look here: https://imgur.com/a/z3XgHfB

Comment: As far as I can see the values are aligned. I mean the correct name gets the correct date. Perhaps you need to do some data manipulation to change the formats or smth

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Knackpy docs](https://cityofaustin.github.io/knackpy/docs/user-guide/#working-with-record-objects), the `App.get()` method returns a list of `Record` objects—they are not dictionaries.

I haven't tested this code, but you almost definitely need to convert your knack records to dicts first. Something like this:

```py
    import knackpy
    app = knackpy.App(app_id = "my-app-id",  api_key = "my-api-key")
    records = app.get("knack_birthdays")

    # you can control wether to format the record field names, values or both. 
    # see knack docs
    records_formatted = [record.format() for record in records]

    fig3 = px.bar(records_formatted, x = 'employee_name', y = 'birthday', title='birthdays')
    fig3.show()
```